# Indenting and creating new space for my array in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
e4 = prompt("Enter the five favorite sports", "hockey,football,basketball,tennis,golf");
e4 = e4.split(",")

for (var i = 0; i < e4.length; i++) {
    if (e4[i] == "football") {
        e4[i] = "soccer";
    }
} 
e5 = prompt("Enter extra sport", "formula 1");
e4.push(e5);

for (var i = 0; i < e4.length; i++) {
    e4[i] = e4[i].toUpperCase();
}
e4.sort();
```

This is my lines of code that would print out like this

```
["BASKETBALL", "FORMULA 1", "GOLF", "HOCKEY", "SOCCKER", "TENNIS]
```

however, what I want to print out is in format such as this:

```
BASKETBALL
FORMULA 1
GOLF
HOCKEY
SOCCER
TENNIS
```

and new lines of other code would start here.

I'm from C++ so im aware of `\n`, but how would you format it like that so it is indented like that above and creating new lines everytime it goes through elements in array?

Comment: (Welcome to SO! For machine input/output, I prefer *block quotes* over *code blocks*.) Have you tried to output characters similar to the example you posted? *In which way* has the look of that been lacking? Do you print "to HTML"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```js
e4 = prompt("Enter the five favorite sports", "hockey,football,basketball,tennis,golf");
e4 = e4.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < e4.length; i++) {
 if (e4[i] == "football") {
  e4[i] = "soccer";
 }
}
e5 = prompt("Enter extra sport", "formula 1");
e4.push(e5);
e4.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < e4.length; i++) {
 e4[i] = e4[i].toUpperCase();
 if (i == e4.length) {
  e4[i] = "    " + e4[i];
 } else {
  e4[i] = "    " + e4[i] + "\n";
 }
}

console.log(e4.toString().replace(/,/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this is a perfect use case `Array#join`

Use `<br/>` tag as a glue in `[].join`

```js
var e4 = prompt("Enter the five favorite sports", "hockey,football,basketball,tennis,golf");
e4 = e4.split(",")

for (var i = 0; i < e4.length; i++) {
  if (e4[i] == "football") {
    e4[i] = "soccer";
  }
}
e5 = prompt("Enter extra sport", "formula 1");
e4.push(e5);

for (var i = 0; i < e4.length; i++) {
  e4[i] = e4[i].toUpperCase();
}
var sorted = e4.sort().join('<br/>');
document.body.innerHTML = sorted;
```